# Problem with here-doc in `print $fh <<'EOF'`: Perl executing the here doc

Tags: perl

(According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/17479551/6607497 it should work, but doesn't)
I have some code like this:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
if (open(my $fh, '>', '/tmp/test')) {
    print $fh << 'TAG';
    BEGIN {
       something;
    }
TAG
    close($fh);
}
```

If I leave out `$fh` (which is a file handle opened for output, BTW), the `BEGIN` block is output correctly (to `STDOUT`).
However when I add `$fh`, Perl (5.18, 5.26) tried to execute `something` which causes an run-time error:

```
Bareword "something" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /tmp/heredoc2.pl line 6.
syntax error at /tmp/heredoc2.pl line 9, near "FOO
    close"
Execution of /tmp/heredoc2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Works for me with your example on Perl 5.26.1.

Comment: The code you posted works as-is (assuming `$fh` contains a valid handle, of course).  Please post the code that actually demonstrates the problem, as required. See [mcve].

Comment: Also, please include the error you received.

Comment: Please remove space after <<. It hurts my eyes.

Comment: @KjetilS. I can't; it's part of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The details of the problem are interesting (Original Perl was 5.18.2, but using 5.26.1 for the example):

First some code that works without `$fh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
if (open(my $fh, '>', '/tmp/test')) {
    print << 'FOO_BAR';
BEGIN {
    something;
}
FOO_BAR
    close($fh);
}
```

`perl -c` says : `/tmp/heredoc.pl syntax OK`, but nothing is output!

If I add `$fh` before `<<`, I get this error:

```perl
Bareword "something" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at /tmp/heredoc.pl line 7.
syntax error at /tmp/heredoc.pl line 10, near "FOO_BAR
    close"
/tmp/heredoc.pl had compilation errors.
```

Finally if I remove the space before `'FOO_BAR'`, it works:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
if (open(my $fh, '>', '/tmp/test')) {
    print $fh <<'FOO_BAR';
BEGIN {
    something;
}
FOO_BAR
    close($fh);
}

> perl -c /tmp/heredoc.pl 
/tmp/heredoc.pl syntax OK
> perl /tmp/heredoc.pl 
> cat /tmp/test
BEGIN {
    something;
}
```

Maybe the true pitfall is the statement in `perlop(1)`:

```
           There may not be a space between the "<<" and the identifier,
           unless the identifier is explicitly quoted.  (...)
```

Comment: Happens with 5.30.2 too, fwiw.

Comment: `<<` in `print << 'FOO_BAR'` is the shift operator

Comment: Note that the OP showed `print $fh <<'TAG';` being used (no space)

Comment: @Shawn: Is "I" direct or indirect speech? I mean: Does "I" mean "you", or does it mean me? ;-) No, I have not filed a bug report yet.

Comment: It means you. Either the documentation is wrong, or the parser is wrong for not following what the documentation says. Either way it's a bug that should be passed on.